# Base pointer to derived object?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

If `Child` inherits from parent, and I do:

```
Child* c = new Child();
Parent* p = c;
```

what is the purpose of `p`? If `Child` contained additional data members, do they follow on from `p`, just that `p` cannot access them?

I am trying to understand the difference between whats actually in memory and what the pointer can access, depending on its static type.

Comment: `p` cannot access them. Or rather, you cannot access them directly through `p`.

Comment: It would be a good exercise to fire up your favorite editor and test this out for yourself!

Comment: It would be a good exercise to open up your C++ book and learn about polymorphism.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: Why would you discard a perfectly compliant compiler? That seems wasteful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Right, I got the inheritance hierarchy inverted.

Answer (score 0):

In the tiny snippet of code shown, it's not possible to tell what MAY be the purpose of `p`. However, in general, using pointer or reference to a base class to store objects that are polymorphic in nature is a common practice. For example, the classic example of shapes:

```
// Base class for all shapes. 
class Shape
{
  ... 
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
  ...
};

class Square: public Shape
{
  ...
};
```

Now, if we want to store a bunch of shapes, we can use:

```
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

shapes.push_back(new Circle);
shapes.push_back(new Square);
```

and then do:

```
for(auto &s : shapes)
{
   s.Draw();    // Draw shapes on screen... 
}
```

The vector needs to hold pointers or references, so that the type is determined by the actual object stored. If we made a vector `std::vector<Shape> shapes`, then we'd get "slicing", where any extra information stored in the `Circle` (such as `radius`) or `Square` (such as `side`) would be lost.

Comment: I think you want `s->Draw()`, as the dereferenced iterator in the range-based-for is a pointer.

Comment: Can we stop propagating the anti-pattern of owning raw pointers?